# Powershell script - scheduled in task sceduler - issue with notepad

Tags: powershell, task, scheduler

I have a powershell script that I have scheduled in task scheduler

The script is as follows:
And its working if I run it directly from powershell

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\TMP\" -include *.* -Recurse |
Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt $startOfToday | ForEach-Object {gc $_; ""} | Set-Content "C:\$(Get-Date 
-Format 'yyyy/MM/dd').txt"
```

The script does not finish when I check the logfiles, it seems that it wants to open notepad, and does not finish the script

Is there a work-aorund for this? Is the problem related to Set-Content? and .txt at the end?

Comment: I don't see any issue in the script. How is the task configured?

Comment: _"it seems that it wants to open notepad"_  What makes you say that?  Since `$startOfToday` isn't defined in the code sample, it appears that this is from a larger script - is there something you're not showing that might cause the issue?

Comment: yes, the problem was in the scheduler, had forgotten to point it as a powershell application

Comment: Question is resolved